# Source control for Azure API Management policies

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

So inside Azure API Management, I have created a policy to cache tokens and self-authenticate itself before hitting the actual API endpoint. I would like to know if there is a way to put these policies in some form of source control such as Azure DevOps or Github and pull them from there or if the azure portal can maintain source control. Any input or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look at [ApiOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/devops/automated-api-deployments-apiops)

Comment: Thank you so much for sending this article. It is really useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to manage the **APIM Policies** with **Azure APIM service**  is to add the Git configuration like below:-

Clone the Azure APIM git repository url in your local machine make changes to the code or the Policies and Publish it back to the APIM resource. Refer this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-configuration-repository-git) for the same.

[image]

[image]

Get git credentials from Access Credentials section in Repository page like below:-

[image]

You can also import this repository in Azure DevOps repository with Above Access credentials like below:-

[image]

I also agree and Thank you **@Markus Meyer** for referencing APIOps extractor tool for managing Azure APIM instances via Azure DevOps repository and Github.

Refer this [**Document**](https://azure.github.io/apiops/apiops/3-apimTools/#configure-apim-tools) on APIOps for APIM.

Add the Azure Devops APIOps tool zipped folder in Azure Devops repository like below and create a variable group referencing your APIM instance parameters like below:-

[**Reference**](https://azure.github.io/apiops/apiops/3-apimTools/apimtools-azdo-2-3-new.html)

[image]

[image]